# When I nack() a pub/sub message it will not be redelivered

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

> It seems that when I Nack a pub/sub message (message.nack()), pub/sub
> dumps the message and never retries to send it again. I also do not
> see an unacknowledged message in the subscription console on google
> cloud. If I don`t acknowledge the message, pub/sub releases the
> message after a time and in that case redeliveres it (with the
> message: Dropping 1 items because they were leased too long).
>
> Service is my own class which will either return the message if it can
> be published, return 'acknowledge' if it is not relevant (acknowledge
> without publishing it) or unacknowledge it, if the service it not yet
> ready to publish it.
>
> I am using the following packages: google-api-core==1.16.0
> google-cloud-pubsub==1.5.0 Flask==1.1.2
>
> The whole service runs with flask on a kubernetes cluster.
>
> ```
> subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials)
> subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_name)
> def callback(message):
>     enriched_message = Service.enrich(promo, message.data, 0)
>
>     # Ckeck if a message has to be published to the topic or not.
>     if enriched_message == 'acknowledge':
>         message.ack()
>     elif enriched_message == 0:
>         message.nack()
>     elif enriched_message != 0:
>         answer = CrmPosService.pub(enriched_message)
>         if answer == 'acknowledge':
>             message.ack()
>
> try:
>     future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
>     # Keep the main thread from exiting so the subscriber can
>     # process messages in the background.
>     while True:
>         time.sleep(1)
> except Exception as ex:
>     logger.error('Could not subscribe')
>     logger.error(ex, exc_info=True)
>     raise ex
> ```

Comment: Are you certain that you are nacking the message (i.e., that enriched_message == 0)? Calling nack() on the message should indeed request that Pub/Sub redeliver the message: https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/index.html#explaining-ack

Comment: Yes I am certain. I had a print('Nack') there which showed up in the console and I also debugged the code. Is there any way to check if the message was really unacknowledged?

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your  subscription `subscription_name`?

Comment: Shure:
Delivery type: Pull
Subscription expiration: Never expire
Acknowledgment deadline: 600 seconds
Message retention duration: 7 days
Retry policy: Retry immediately

Comment: Found the error: I was testing local, while the service was also running in a kubernetes cluster. When I unacknowledged a message local the subscribtion then send the message to the other subscriber, thats why I never saw it local twice..